# Getting duplicates in my datatable

Tags: javascript, arrays, datatable

I'm new to JavaScript.

I only have three entries in my database but when I run the code listed below I get six results. One entry shows up 3x while the other two entries show up 2x. What might I be doing wrong?

```
 var tidyAppts='';
query.find({
success: function(results) {
// Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
  var object = results[i];
  //alert(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('ZipCode'));
  tidyAppts+='<tr><td>'
   + object.get('Name') + '<td><td>' 
   + object.get('Phone') + '<td><td>' 
   + object.get('Address') + '<td><td>' 
   + object.get('ZipCode') + '<td><td>' 
   + object.get('Frequency') + '<td><td>' 
   + object.get('TIDY') + '</td><td>'
   + object.get('FirstTIDYDay') + '</td><td>'
   + object.get('TIDYTime') + '</td><td>'
   + object.get('SecondTIDYDay') + '</td><td>'
   + object.get('SecondTIDYApptTime') + '</td><td>'
   + object.get('ThirdTIDYDay') + '</td><td>' 
   + object.get('ThirdTIDYApptTime') + '</td></tr>';
  (function($) {
            $('#tidy-appt-table').append(tidyAppts);
        })(jQuery);
}
```

},

When I used this code, only the first 4 objects for each entry is displayed in the table but I get the correct amount of records which is 3.

```
 (function($) {

            $('#tidy-appt-table').append('<tr><td>' 

                + object.get('Name') 

                + '</td><td>' 

                + object.get('Phone') 

                + '</td><td>'

                + object.get('Address') 

                + '</td></td>'

                + object.get('ZipCode') 

                + '</td></td>'

                + object.get('Frequency') 

                + '</td></td>' 

                + object.get('TIDY') 

                + '</td><td>' 

                + object.get('FirstTIDYDay') 

                + '</td><td>' 

                + object.get('TIDYTime') 

                + '</td><td>' 

                + object.get('SecondTIDYDay') 

                + '</td></td>')

                + object.get('SecondTIDYApptTime') 

                + '</td></td>'

                + object.get('ThirdTIDYDay') 

                + '</td></td>'

                + object.get('ThirdTIDYApptTime') 

                + '</td></tr>';



        })(jQuery);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out I removed the plus sign from tidyAppts+='' and made it tidyAppts=